I am trying to create a google sign in button in my app using credential manager but im struggling with a certain error
This is my code for the sign in flow
CredentialManager credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(context);
                GetGoogleIdOption googleIdOption = new GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
                        .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                        .setServerClientId("1043676395397-flo4592nvuma1c98bnk7fbkfpfi1hj88.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                        .build();
                GetCredentialRequest request = new GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
                        .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
                        .build();

                credentialManager.getCredentialAsync(context, request, new CredentialManagerCallback<GetCredentialResponse, GetCredentialException>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(GetCredentialResponse result) {
                                handleSignIn(result);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(GetCredentialException e) {

                                handleFailure(e);
                            }
                        }
                );

And this is my code for handling sign ins
public void handleSignIn(GetCredentialResponse result) {
        Credential credential = result.getCredential();
        if (credential instanceof PublicKeyCredential) {
            String responseJson = ((PublicKeyCredential) credential).getAuthenticationResponseJson();
        } else if (credential instanceof PasswordCredential) {
            String username = ((PasswordCredential) credential).getId();
            String password = ((PasswordCredential) credential).getPassword();
        } else if (credential instanceof CustomCredential) {
            if (GoogleIdTokenCredential.TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL.equals(credential.getType())) {
                GoogleIdTokenCredential googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential.createFrom(((CustomCredential) credential).getData());
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected type of credential");
            }
        } else {
            // Catch any unrecognized credential type here.
            Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected type of credential");
        }
    }

The error seems to be from here specifically on the public void onError(GetCredentialException e) part here
credentialManager.getCredentialAsync(context, request, new CredentialManagerCallback<GetCredentialResponse, GetCredentialException>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(GetCredentialResponse result) {
                                handleSignIn(result);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(GetCredentialException e) {

                                handleFailure(e);
                            }
                        }
                );

The error is the handlefailure(e)
I tried searching for a solution but the only one that came up is that I replace the code with this
credentialManager.getCredentialAsync(context, request, new CredentialManagerCallback<GetCredentialResponse, GetCredentialException>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(GetCredentialResponse result) {
                                MainActivity.this.handleSignIn(result);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(GetCredentialException e) {

                                MainActivity.this.handleFailure(e);
                            }
                        }
                );


Include the "certain error" in your post.

I have added a picture to describe the error thank you for taking the time to look at my code @Computable.

Include the handleFailure() code from MainActivity.  Btw, it is preferred to include any supporting information as text - not pictures - and your picture doesn't show any error information anyways.  I notice in android docs it does not include a handleFailure in example code - so maybe you're just missing it as well.

Unfortunately the code that I got from here https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/passkeys#java does not include anything about handleFailure() only that it is added  in the onError. I have tried searching other answers regarding this but all of the code I have seen do not show the code for handleFailure()

Then remove the call to handleFailure or create one and just add a Log statement (similar to other code) until you have specific reasons to handle the error - you'll likely need to think about UI workflow if user attempts are failed - if user presses button and it fails the user should expect an error message that leads them to fixing the issue, for example.

I have tried replacing it with this
"public void onError (GetCredentialException e) {
Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected type of credential");
}"
but I am met with this error "
no suitable method found for getCredentialAsync(Context,GetCredentialRequest,<anonymous CredentialManagerCallback<GetCredentialResponse,GetCredentialException>>)
credentialManager.getCredentialAsync(context, request, new CredentialManagerCallback<GetCredentialResponse, GetCredentialException>() {"
